# Three.js touching faces artifacts

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency, artifacts

I've created two transparent boxes whose faces touch. This works great unless the boxes' faces touch.

```
// inner object
var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 

mesh2.position.x = 0;
mesh2.position.y = 0;
mesh2.position.z = 0;

mesh2.scale.x = 100;
mesh2.scale.y = 50;
mesh2.scale.z = 100;

scene.add( mesh2 ); 

// outer object
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 

mesh1.position.x = 0;
mesh1.position.y = 0;
mesh1.position.z = 0;

mesh1.scale.x = 100;
mesh1.scale.y = 100;
mesh1.scale.z = 100; 

scene.add( mesh1 );
```

Here's the code: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/unkya/14/

How do I get rid of these artifacts and still have the faces touch?

Also, is there a way to add the boxes to the scene without having to insert the inner most ones first?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

There are two ways around this.

The first is simply to offset the values by a small amount. Even 0.01 might do it. The important part here is to ensure your camera's [near plane and far plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) are within ranges that are reasonable.

The second way is to use the [polygonOffset](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2593) property of THREE.js materials. This will allow you to force an object to render above or below other objects, similar to a z-index ordering. I believe transparency also needs to be enabled, so you should put this on your semi-transparent cube if possible.